# What are the appropriate steps to showing a one to one correspondence?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Let me give a specific example.  Consdier the problem of the number of ways of assigning values to k positive integers x1,x2,...,xk such that their sum is less than or equal to some number n.  One way of solving this is to introduce an  additional variable y and find the number of ways that the k+1 variables add up to n+1. The number of ways of doing this corresponds to the stars and bars formula C(n+1-1,k+1-1)=C(n,k). If we can show a one to one correspondence between the k variables having sums <= n with the k+1 variables adding up to n+1, then the answer would be Cn,k). Note that n+1 is used for the sum of the k+1 variables since y is at least equal to 1, so if the x values add to n the k+1 variables add up to at least n+1.

To show one to one correspondence, we can say that for each set of k+1 variables adding to n+1, we can use the k x values adding up to some value <= n.  Furthermore, for each set of x values that add to a number <= n, we can find a value of y such that the k+1 variables add to n+1. Is that sufficient for showing one to one correspondence? Or is it necessary to do more?  What if we showed that for every two sets of k+1 of variables adding to n+1, the corresponding two sets of k x variables are different?

Comment: "To show one to one correspondence, we can say that for each set of k+1 variables adding to n+1, we can use the k x values adding up to some value <= n" : assuming that I have not mis-interpreted your posting, I completely agree.  The 1-1 correspondence can be shown as you suggested.  So, in my opinion, your analysis is both accurate and valid.

Comment: Going forward, with your future MathSE postings, consider that your posting would become significantly easier to digest via judicious use of paragraph breaks and line breaks.  The line breaks are done via `<br>`.

Comment: Seems to me that the sentence you quoted is insufficient for showing one to one corresondence.  What if "n+1" was replaced by "n"?  The statement would be true, but there would no longer be a one to one correspondence. At the very least it seems to be necessary to show that x values adding to value <=n can be mapped to k+1 variables adding to n+1.

Comment: **To the OP (i.e. original poster):** I found the posting very confusingly written, and so I read *between the lines*, attempting to interpret what was intended.  I agree that the quoted sentence, by itself is insufficient.  However, I think that it is the right starting point for constructing the 1-1 correspondence.  In this instance, I simply assumed (perhaps wrongly) that the analysis intended by the OP is valid.  It is difficult to grapple with formality when the posting is so poorly paragraph/line break written, with possible rambling.